# how to check onclick function is fired or not in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, enzyme

Could you please tell me how to check onclick function is fired or not in react?
I have one button in my demo `INCREMENT` onclick of button I want to check is `onClickHandler` function called or not

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
it("check counter increment function is callled", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  });
```

Comment: did you tried using a console.log ?

Comment: not working https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

Comment: for me the onclick is working fine

Comment: test case man ,,,I need to check test case

Comment: Console.log is not really solving any problems when writing automated tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a library like sinon to spy on your class functions:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
```

Then, when you set up your tests, before you shallow render your Component:

```
it("check counter increment function is called", () => {
  const spy = sandbox.spy(Counter.prototype, 'onClickHandler');
  const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  expect(spy.called).toBe(true);
});
```

**Update:**

The onClickHandler should not be defined as an anonymous function, instead use:

```
onClickHandler() {
  const incrementCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
  this.setState({
    counter: incrementCounter
  });
}
```

And in your render function, bind this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
      <button onClick{this.onClickHandler.bind(this)}>INCREMENT</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update using Jest**

Actually, you don't even need a third-party library like sinon. You can achieve the same thing using Jest:

```
it("check counter increment function is called", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Counter.prototype, "onClickHandler");
  const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
  wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
  expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: That's because your onClickHandler is dfined as an anonymous function (fat arrow function). Try he following and it works:
onClickHandler() {
    const increamentCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
    this.setState({
      counter: increamentCounter
    });
  }

Comment: Isn't it `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();` with jest ?

Comment: Different matcher - same effect ;) Just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Add `console.log()` in your onClick :

```
it("check counter increment function is callled", () => {
    console.log('Im here')
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
 });
```

Comment: That is not really helpful when you try to achieve this in an automated test.

Answer (score -1):

I added console log to your code and it was working fine.

```
     onClickHandler = () => {
         console.log("Hello");
          const incrementCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
            this.setState({
            counter: incrementCounter
          });
       };
```

So the onClickHandler is working fine. For the failed test, I think this [link](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/305) might be helpful

Comment: console.logging is not really useful when writing automated tests